# Can I get the data of WCF Service with PHP?

Tags: php, wcf

Like the heading, I want to get the data from WCF Service http://daklak.qlnt.net/c3lehongphong/DP.svc in PHP. The structure of XML is something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <Fetch xmlns="http://ws.lhotka.net/WcfDataPortal">
         <request xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Csla.Server.Hosts.Mobile" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <d4p1:ClientContext>eNpNibEKwyAURe1XdPUDRCwmlAxOyZalQ+hu7A1IReHlCc3fx2w9cO5wz00IcXnfxj15PRZCm8z48RQDx5I9HUpeUck3aG+P63Svn+ahTQs1cSW4jMrkk5KvuqYYZhxL+SK7wa7ot08wg0UXrBF/nO7PIuY=</d4p1:ClientContext>
            <d4p1:ClientCulture i:nil="true" />
            <d4p1:ClientUICulture i:nil="true" />
            <d4p1:CriteriaData>eNrNkr1OwzAUhZP+UBhQB4ZkzE5kpUpC6NABUiGqFoFoxcBSOcktmEZx6p8hTwCPjdO4tAsSE6ot68pXx/J3jm7HMAxTHevLnN+gOaS0yDCr0K3kpADO0TOUlAmOpiA2Es8IF5cxIwIYwa4zV29+lJOilMJ1XoBxQovRAHn1dp1Y5kIyGBUgBcO56zzJJCfpFKoFXYMSBhEOwuTq2h9EEGLP2CGdL1cE8uwBF/gNmLlt91pGs+pqsZjnGMWUAbo7kDaXMRZYNxSEEu7ZAhSiyBv8hW7oJxCustQb+hCkvtfa0fXuaaqcv7cbrvaO6WKZ6EQekw9IxaIqoU7ZMrpbZf94kra6ysO6OlFcdgN3Zup4azvW5y+k2/+R9v8foD0duq2HoKMp62ofToTd2XvpHw2+1Z2MZ7Q8Pcj5VUN/A5wo+Jk=</d4p1:CriteriaData>
            <d4p1:GlobalContext>eNpNibEKwyAURe1XdPUDRCwmlAxOyZalQ+hu7A1IReHlCc3fx2w9cO5wz00IcXnfxj15PRZCm8z48RQDx5I9HUpeUck3aG+P63Svn+ahTQs1cSW4jMrkk5KvuqYYZhxL+SK7wa7ot08wg0UXrBF/nO7PIuY=</d4p1:GlobalContext>
            <d4p1:Principal>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</d4p1:Principal>
            <d4p1:TypeName>SA.Secondary.Business.Reports.KetquaList, SSA.Business.Input, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=147a45b68317e5a0</d4p1:TypeName>
         </request>
      </Fetch>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Note: This XML is captured from a silverlight app's traffic.